# Interrupt loop python after a certain string have been printed

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a bicycle list like this :

```
fmnewlist = [
    ['Bike No.', 'Purchase Date', 'Batt %', 'Last Maintenance', 'KM since Last', 'Reason/s'], 
    ['T101', '10/4/2016', '55', '10/1/2017', '25.08', 'No service'], 
    ['T102', '1/7/2016', '10', '15/5/2017', '30.94', 'No service'], 
    ['T103', '15/11/2016', '94', '13/6/2017', '83.16', 'KM'], 
    ['T104', '25/4/2017', '58', '10/1/2017', '25.08', 'No service'], 
    ['T105', '24/5/2017', '5', '20/6/2017', '93.8', 'Batt & KM']
]
```

and I want to check for certain elements in each of the inner lists and then print a string out like this without it looping. Here's my code, why doesn't it work?

```
lens=len(fmnewlist)
biketocheck=(input("Bike No.:"))
countertwo=1

while countertwo < (lens+1):
    a=fmnewlist[countertwo]
    if biketocheck in a[0] and a[5]!="No service":
        print("Bike serviced.")
    elif biketocheck in a[0] and a[5]=="No service":
        print("Bicycle not due for servicing")
    elif biketocheck not in fmnewlist:
        print("No such bicycle")
    else:
        print(" ")
    countertwo+=1
    if countertwo==lens:
        break
```

expected output when `T123` is entered:

```
Bike No.:T123
No such bicycle
```

real output:

```
Bike No.:T123
No such bicycle
No such bicycle
No such bicycle
No such bicycle
No such bicycle
```

expected output when input is `T102`:

`Bicycle not due for servicing`

real output:

`Bike No.:T102
No such bicycle
Bicycle not due for servicing
No such bicycle
No such bicycle
No such bicycle`

expected output when input is `T103`:

`Bike serviced`
Real output:

`Bike No.:T103
No such bicycle
No such bicycle
Bike serviced.
No such bicycle
No such bicycle`

Comment: Just add a `break` wherever you want to exit the loop. (E.g. after the line `print("No such bicycle")`.)

Comment: You print something for *every row in your input rows*. If you don't want to print `No such bicycle` for every row you test, don't print it for every row. Set a flag and only print it after looping.

Comment: yeah but if I do that ,the others elif wouldnt work @smarx

Comment: @MartijnPieters how do I do that?

Comment: @NathanLeow I'm not sure what you mean. What other `elif`, and perhaps you can explain more clearly under what circumstances you want to exit the loop.

Comment: well for example  if I put a `break` after `if biketocheck in a[0] and a[5]!="No service":
        print("Bike serviced.")`
the next line of code `elif biketocheck in a[0] and a[5]=="No service":
        print("Bicycle not due for servicing")` wouldnt run

Comment: for some reason

Comment: I'm suggesting the `break` goes *inside* that `if` block. The code in the `elif` wouldn't run anyway (since the first condition already matched).

Comment: Note that `'T102' in fmnewlist` is never going to be true; containment tests on a list are not recursive (it won't check the contents of nested lists).

Comment: What Martijn said. You really should check if the bike is in the list first, before you check the service info. And you could make the whole thing more efficient by using a `dict` instead of a `list`. That way, you wouldn't need a loop. Fortunately, it's very easy to convert that data to a `dict`.

Comment: @NathanLeow: you could [edit] your question to add that last observation. Multiple test cases and expected output only helps explain your problem better.

Comment: alright I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best guess as to what the program is supposed to do:

1. Look through the list of bikes for a row where the first element matches a user-specified ID.
2. If the bike is not found, print "No such bicycle."
3. If the bike is found, print out either "Bicycle not due for servicing" or "Bike serviced" depending on the value of the 6th element.

Given those assumptions, I believe this code should do what you want:

```
fmnewlist = [
    ['Bike No.', 'Purchase Date', 'Batt %', 'Last Maintenance', 'KM since Last', 'Reason/s'], 
    ['T101', '10/4/2016', '55', '10/1/2017', '25.08', 'No service'], 
    ['T102', '1/7/2016', '10', '15/5/2017', '30.94', 'No service'], 
    ['T103', '15/11/2016', '94', '13/6/2017', '83.16', 'KM'], 
    ['T104', '25/4/2017', '58', '10/1/2017', '25.08', 'No service'], 
    ['T105', '24/5/2017', '5', '20/6/2017', '93.8', 'Batt & KM']
]

biketocheck=(input("Bike No.:"))

found = False
for bike in fmnewlist[1:]:
    if bike[0] == biketocheck:
        found = True

        if bike[5] == "No service":
            print("Bicycle not due for servicing")
        else:
            print("Bike serviced.")
        break

if not found:
    print("No such bicycle")
```

**EDIT**

Using a `dict` instead, which makes the logic a little easier:

```
bikes = { bike[0]:bike[1:] for bike in fmnewlist[1:] }

biketocheck=(input("Bike No.:"))

if biketocheck in bikes:
    if bikes[biketocheck][4] == "No service":
        print("Bicycle not due for servicing")
    else:
        print("Bike serviced.")
else:
    print("No such bicycle")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a lookup map of your list and do quick `if .. in` comparisons, something like:

```
fmnewlist = [
    ['Bike No.', 'Purchase Date', 'Batt %', 'Last Maintenance','KM since Last', 'Reason/s'], 
    ['T101', '10/4/2016', '55', '10/1/2017', '25.08', 'No service'], 
    ['T102', '1/7/2016', '10', '15/5/2017', '30.94', 'No service'], 
    ['T103', '15/11/2016', '94', '13/6/2017', '83.16', 'KM'], 
    ['T104', '25/4/2017', '58', '10/1/2017', '25.08', 'No service'], 
    ['T105', '24/5/2017', '5', '20/6/2017', '93.8', 'Batt & KM']
]

bike_iter = iter(fmnewlist)  # create an iterator for easier handling
next(bike_iter)  # skip the first item (header)
bike_nos = {bike[0]: bike[5] for bike in bike_iter}  # create bike_no: reason map

biketocheck = input("Bike No.: ")  # get the input

if biketocheck in bike_nos:  # check if the bike exists
    if bike_nos[biketocheck] == "No service":  # if it exists, check for status...
        print("Bicycle not due for servicing")
    else:
        print("Bike serviced.")
else:  # bike doesn't exist...
    print("No such bicycle")
```

And if you test it:

```
Bike No.: T103
Bike serviced.

Bike No.: T102
Bicycle not due for servicing

Bike No.: T123
No such bicycle
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` instead of `while`, remove the `else` part. Then you can use the `else` statement for `for`:

```
for bicycle in fmnewlist[1:]:  # Don't use the first line
    # previous statements except else, it should have a `break` too.
    if biketocheck in a[0]:
        if a[5]!="No service":
            print("Bike serviced.")
        # compare is either != or == so there's no need to write the whole elif 
        else:
            print("Bicycle not due for servicing")
        break
else:
    print("No such bicycle")
```

`else` will only be used if `for` was completed without a break in it. So it means no bicycle was found. What you are doing is checking each line for the needed bicycle and of course it doesn't exist in that element.

P.S: You can use `else` with `while` too. But you have to be certain that the condition returns `False` after awhile or `else` clause won't work. It's easier with `for` to do it.